# PackageReference not copying all files in lib folder to bin

Tags: nuget-package, packagereference

I have csproj called MyBuilder.csproj using .net framework 4.8 referencing a package called "Me" like so:

```
<PackageReference Include="Me" Version="2.1.2.7-me" />
```

When this package gets pulled in, it gets stored to:
C:\Users\jb.nuget\packages\me\2.1.2.7-me\lib\net48 (Note: I am not referencing anything else within this package in my csproj)

And it pulls in the correct files:
[image]

Now anytime I try to build my csproj or restore the packages, it only copies Me.exe to MyBuilder.csproj's working bin directory. Why does Me.exe.config not also get copied over?

I know I can add a Me.targets file and specify a build step to copy everything over. But is there not a more natural/simple way to have everything in my lib folder copied over to the MyBuilder.csproj's working bin directory? Additionally, does anyone know explain why Me.exe gets copied over and not other contents? Thanks in advance!